# Obtener registros de base de datos con ajax sin usar jquery ni json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

tengo una duda, para un proyecto de la universidad debo extraer los registros de una base de datos (en este caso maria db mediante phpmyadmin) y colocarlos en una tabla que hay en mi formulario, la cual se debe ir actualizando en tiempo real, en internet leí que se suele hacer con archivos json, sin embargo, no es parte de los temas vistos en la universidad, existe alguna alternativa que no incluya la conversion a json? estoy trabajando con ajax en js normal (no jquery) y php, además de la base de datos mencionada anteriormente, muchas gracias.

Comment: JSON: JavaScript Object Notation. ¿Cuál es el problema con que trabajes con JSON, si ya estás trabajando con JS puro?

Comment: JSON es muy sencillo, no añadirá complejidad a tu proyecto, al contrario la reducirá. Es solo un formato para texto plano que se asemeja al formato de objetos de javascript. Podría haber sido cualquier otro como el CSV que separa por punto y coma. Pero fue este el que ganó, donde básicamente es un diccionario de `{clave : valor}`. Es un texto que sirve para transferir objetos entre sistemas. Por otro lado tu hablas de `tiempo real`, entonces creo que AJAX no te sirve

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, las tomaré en cuenta

Comment: JSON tiene muchísimas ventajas, y por eso se usa tanto en casi todos los entornos: es ligero, es sencillo al tiempo que permite anidar objetos complejos, es estructurado. Por ejemplo, algo que me encanta de JSON es que puedes mapearlo con una sencillez asombrosa a objetos de tu modelo de datos. Imagina una App compleja donde recibes un JSON enorme. Con mapearlo a un objeto e invocar algo como `elObjetoMapeado.showTable()` te mostraría tu tabla sin tener que hacer nada más.